# Name of special chain matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

I often run come across a special chain matrix product $ABA^T$, $A^TBA$ or $ABA^{-1}$, $A^{-1}BA$. Do these operations have a special name?

Comment: The last two are called similarity transform. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity The other two I've heard under the name congruence transform. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is “conjugation.” The operation $B \mapsto ABA^{-1}$ is often called conjugation by $A$ (so $B \mapsto A^{-1}BA$ would be conjugation by $A^{-1}$). Using the transpose rather then the inverse would just be a different type of conjugation. Note that both the transpose and inverse have the properties $(A^*)^*$ and $(AB)^* = B^*A^*$. These properties are significant because they allow $(ABA^*)^* =AB^*A^*.$ You can read a bit about the concept as it pertains to algebra here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class

Comment: Could you leave it as an answer, so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

The common word for this in *conjugation*, although the use is not entirely standard.

When you conjugate with $A$ and its inverse it is often called *[similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity)*.